# VS Code Typescript syntaxhighlighting is gone

Tags: visual-studio-code

My syntax highlighting for typescript is gone.
All the other languages are fine.

Things like `import`, `from`, `const` are still **blue**, but if I use `Array<any>` it only shows up in white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure that no extensions are messing with this. Launch vscode from the command line with the command `code --disable-extensions` and see if the coloring works.
2. Install a new theme or two and see if that fixes the syntax highlighting.
3. Are you using the normal builds or the insiders builds? Have you updated recently? What could have changed in your installation or environment?
4. If nothing else works, open an issue with the team on github because there might be a bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues